# Quarkus - Openshift - route.annotations

Tags: routes, openshift, quarkus

I´m using Quarkus and trying quarkus.openshift.route.annotations to set something like this:

port:
targetPort: 8080-tcp
tls:
insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
termination: edge

I found just some weard annotations like
quarkus.openshift.route.annotations."kubernetes.io/tls-acme"=true

So... how can i use this to my route be exposed as https ?
Or there is another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way than configuring tls on your Route.

I do know however, that for Routes the Quarkus openshift extension will allow you to specify host and annotations pretty much like you've already found yourself.

If your goal is achievable using annotations, you are covered. If not you'll need to `bring your own Route`: Just through an openshift.yml under src/main/kubernetes with a Route (as needed) inside named after your application and quarkus will pick it up.

This is something we can definitely improve. Both the user experience and the provided documentation.

**Edit**: Created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20644

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I will manually edit the .yml for now!
How can i help on this git issue?

Comment: If you could provide some example Routes that work for you, it would be awesome! Pull requests are also welcome and I can help on that front, if this is what you mean!